# consuming a web service - JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean or Controller not configured right

Tags: spring-mvc, web-client

Java 1.7
Spring 3.1.1 with Spring-WS 2.1.1
Joda
Hibernate 3.6
MySQL 5.0.57
Maven 3
Tomcat 7
Eclipse 3.7

So the SOAP web service is up and running.

And my standalone Java app can access it.

Now I'm trying to build a Spring MVC web client to access it. So by my way of thinking I can just replace the standard webapp's service layer with the web service endpoint .

Patterning after this
http://ankeetmaini.wordpress.com/2013/03/04/jax-ws-client-consuming-the-jax-ws-webservice
after switching his naming conventions to be more canonical I wound up with

FormsEndpointImplService

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "FormsEndpointImplService", 
                  wsdlLocation = "http://localhost:8080/dept_forms_webservice/formsService?wsdl",
                  targetNamespace = "http://endpoint.web.forms.azdeq.gov/") 
public class FormsEndpointImplService extends Service
{
    public final static URL WSDL_LOCATION;

    public final static QName SERVICE = new QName("http://endpoint.web.forms.azdeq.gov/", "FormsEndpointImplService");
    public final static QName FormsEndpointImplPort = new QName("http://endpoint.web.forms.azdeq.gov/", "FormsEndpointImplPort");
    static {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/dept_forms_webservice/formsService?wsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FormsEndpointImplService.class.getName())
                .log(java.util.logging.Level.INFO, 
                     "Can not initialize the default wsdl from {0}", "http://localhost:8080/dept_forms_webservice/formsService?wsdl");
        }
        WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    }

    public FormsEndpointImplService(URL wsdlLocation) {
        super(wsdlLocation, SERVICE);
    }

    public FormsEndpointImplService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }

    public FormsEndpointImplService() {
        super(WSDL_LOCATION, SERVICE);
    }

    //This constructor requires JAX-WS API 2.2. You will need to endorse the 2.2
    //API jar or re-run wsdl2java with "-frontend jaxws21" to generate JAX-WS 2.1
    //compliant code instead.
    public FormsEndpointImplService(WebServiceFeature ... features) {
        super(WSDL_LOCATION, SERVICE, features);
    }

    //This constructor requires JAX-WS API 2.2. You will need to endorse the 2.2
    //API jar or re-run wsdl2java with "-frontend jaxws21" to generate JAX-WS 2.1
    //compliant code instead.
    public FormsEndpointImplService(URL wsdlLocation, WebServiceFeature ... features) {
        super(wsdlLocation, SERVICE, features);
    }

    //This constructor requires JAX-WS API 2.2. You will need to endorse the 2.2
    //API jar or re-run wsdl2java with "-frontend jaxws21" to generate JAX-WS 2.1
    //compliant code instead.
    public FormsEndpointImplService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName, WebServiceFeature ... features) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName, features);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     returns FormsEndpoint
     */
    @WebEndpoint(name = "FormsEndpointImplPort")
    public FormsEndpoint getFormsEndpointImplPort() {
        return super.getPort(FormsEndpointImplPort, FormsEndpoint.class);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param features
     *     A list of {@link javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature} to configure on the proxy.  Supported features not in the <code>features</code> parameter will have their default values.
     * @return
     *     returns FormsEndpoint
     */
    @WebEndpoint(name = "FormsEndpointImplPort")
    public FormsEndpoint getFormsEndpointImplPort(WebServiceFeature... features) {
        return super.getPort(FormsEndpointImplPort, FormsEndpoint.class, features);
    }
}
```

FormsEndpoint   ( the SEI )

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://endpoint.web.forms.azdeq.gov/", name = "FormsEndpoint")
@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class})
public interface FormsEndpoint
{
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "insertCompletedForm", targetNamespace = "http://endpoint.web.forms.azdeq.gov/", className = "gov.azdeq.forms.web.endpoint.InsertCompletedForm")
    @WebMethod
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "insertCompletedFormResponse", targetNamespace = "http://endpoint.web.forms.azdeq.gov/", className = "gov.azdeq.forms.web.endpoint.InsertCompletedFormResponse")
    public void insertCompletedForm(
        @WebParam(name = "arg0", targetNamespace = "")
        gov.azdeq.forms.web.endpoint.CompletedForm arg0
    );
....
```

}

and my servlet-context.xml

```
...
<bean id="formsWebServiceProxy" class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl"  value="http://localhost:8080/dept_forms_webservice/formsService?wsdl"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="gov.azdeq.forms.web.endpoint.FormsEndpoint"/>
    <property name="serviceName"      value="FormsEndpointImplService"/>
    <property name="portName"         value="FormsEndpointImplPort"/>
    <property name="namespaceUri"     value="http://endpoint.web.forms.azdeq.gov/"/>
    <!-- <property name="endpointAddress" value="http://endpoint.web.forms.azdeq.gov/" />   -->
</bean>

<bean id="baseController"             class="gov.azdeq.forms.web.controller.BaseController">
  <property name="service"            ref="formsWebServiceProxy" />
</bean>

...
```

and Base Controller

```
@RequestMapping
@Controller
public class BaseController
{
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger( BaseController.class);

    @Resource 
    FormsEndpoint service; // should come in from bean
    ...
}
```

So this all compiles and deploys to Tomcat just fine.
But when I click on dept_forms_webclient in localhost:8080/manager  it throws this:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'service' of bean class [gov.azdeq.forms.web.controller.BaseController]: Bean property 'service' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

Seems like the proxy bean is being injected ok, it seems like I should not be setting it to FormsEndpoint regardless of what various tuts say.

So, more configuration confusion, can anyone spot what's wrong here?

TIA,

Still-learning Stev

Comment: Remote the xml declaration for `baseController` you are using annotations for injections not manual configuration. Or add a setter for the service property (which is what the exception is actually telling you).

Answer (score 1):

I got it all working by losing the dependency-injection in the context file and using @Autowired in the controller like so:

```
<!-- controllers -->      
<bean id="baseController"                   class="gov.azdeq.forms.web.controller.BaseController" />
```

and

```
@RequestMapping
@Controller("baseController")
public class BaseController
{
    @Autowired
    @Resource(name="formsWebServicePortProxy")
    FormsEndpoint   formsWebServicePortProxy;
```

Not sure why using @Autowired works but manual property injection does not. Huh.

Thanks to all who replied, it did give me a bit of insight.

CASE CLOSED

Still-learning Steve